# MySQL - ¿Cómo hacer Select ordenando por columnas en un orden deseado y/o omitir una columna?

Tags: mysql, select

necesito crear una query(select) la cual me muestre las columnas en el orden que yo desee. 
Aquí mi tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.- Quiero que mi select muestre primero las columnas "ingresoanual","numerodecasas" pero luego me muestre las demás pero sin tener que hacer esto `select ingresoanual, numerodecasas,nombre,apellido,... from tabla;`, en SQL Server puedo hacer esto `select col14, col8, * from tabla;` y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacerlo en MySQL.

2.- Resulta que en mi select quiero me muestre todas las columnas, menos la columna id.
y no quisiera hacer `select nombre, apellidos, ... , numerodehijos from tabla;`
la única manera sería creando una vista?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql creo que es lo mismo que estas buscando

Comment: mi solución es la siguiente aunque te van ha salir repetidos los campos SELECT t2.col14, t2.col8, t1.* FROM tabla as t1 INNER JOIN tabla as t2 ON t1.idtab=t2.idtab